# Parse.com: Mobile device not "saving" file

Tags: javascript, android, parse-platform

this code works great on the desktop, but not on a mobile device( with Ionic)... The problem is when it is to run .save(), nothing happens:

```
$scope.profilePictureSave=function(){
    var fileUploadControl=document.getElementById("profilePictureUpload");
    if(fileUploadControl.files.length>0){
        var file=fileUploadControl.files[0];
        var name="photo.jpg";

        var parseFile=new Parse.File(name,file);

        parseFile.save().then(function(){
            Parse.User.current().set("profile_picture",parseFile);
            Parse.User.current().save(null,{
                success:function(results){$scope.$apply();
                $window.location.reload(true)},
                error:function(error){alert(error.code+" "+error.message);}
            });
        },function(error){});
    }
    $scope.modal.hide();
}
```

Comment: Plese provide the error message on the parseFile.save() ..... try this -> },function(error){alert(error.code+" "+error.message)});

Comment: It does not produce an error. An alert placed right before the .save() will fire, but then anything after the .save() does not.